# Error in Entity frame work6.0.0.0:type has not been explicitly excluded by using the Ignore method or NotMappedAttribute data annotation

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have a grid view and object data source on webpage.Below are the classes created for code first approach.

```
public class Department
{
    public int deptId{ get; set; }
    public string deptName { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public List<Employee>Employees { get; set; }
    //CodeFirstExample.Employee edf = new Employee();

}

public class Employee
{
    public int empId { get; set; }
    public string empName { get; set; }
    public int salary { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeDBContext:DbContext
{

  public  DbSet<Department> Departments{ get; set; }
  public   DbSet <List<Employee>> Employees { get; set; }
}
public class EmployeeRepository
{
    public List<Department> GetDepartments()
    {
        EmployeeDBContext emp = new EmployeeDBContext();

        return emp.Departments.ToList();
    }
}
```

in web.config file connection string as fllowed

```
 <connectionStrings>
      <add name="EmployeeDBContext" 
             connectionString="data source=.\SQLSERVER;initial catalog=Sample; integrated security=SSPI"
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
      </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Your `DbSet` for the employees has the incorrect type, don't use `List<Employee>`, just use `Employee`.

Comment: Worth noting that the error message likely told you this, it pays to read them properly - and post the full messages here for us to see.

Comment: thanks a lot. Your suggestion working fine